# php: having difficulty implementing rtrim()

Tags: trim

I've looked at several examples of the implementation of rtrim(), and I'm not able to implement it in my particular case.

Here's what I tried:

```
if ( $memberRoles = xprofile_get_field_data( 'AD Roles', bp_get_member_user_id() ) ) :

        foreach ( $memberRoles as $memberRoles ) { 
                    echo '<div class="roles"><h5>';
                    echo $memberRoles; 
                    echo ',&nbsp</h5></div>';
                }

            endif;

            $memberRoles = rtrim($memberRoles, ",");
```

I'm still very nascent when it comes to writing code, and even more so when it comes to php. Any help or advice is greatly, greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! This spits out a list of items, and I would like to remove the last comma after the last item. Currently displays: "item1, item2, item3,"

Comment: Just calling `rtrim("item1, item2, item3,", ",")` indeed produced `"item1, item2, item3"`, so there must be something else going on here. Are you **sure** that's the value of `$memberRoles`?

Comment: $memberRoles is currently displaying the items (live on site), so I'm fairly certain it is the value. Again, I really appreciate you having a look at this.